How to log in into another session when the screen is locked?
I used to be able to log in with another account when locking the first session. However, ever since I updated to 24.04 from 23.10 this option disappeared. I can only see this screen:

What may be going on here? I'm using lightdm but can easily use gdm3 too.

As far as I can remember going back ~15 years, the lock screen has never given an option to login as another user. You need to switch back to the login screen using Ctrl-Alt-F1 (or F7, depending on the DM)

Press CtrlAltF1 (or F7, depending on the display manager) to get back to the display manager's login screen. You can login as another user from there.
